# Why does Angular call the SCSS file every time Ctrl + F5 is pressed?

Tags: angular

I'm having an issue with Angular, when I press Ctrl + F5, the CSS file is reloaded, which breaks my layout until the CSS file finishes loading. There's no issue with F5 because the CSS file is cached.

I expect Angular not to reload the CSS file when pressing Ctrl + F5

Comment: Welcome! Why would you expect the CSS not to reload? You're hard refreshing your browser which clears cache. This isn't an Angular specific issue, it's the browser.

Comment: However, this breaks my layout briefly. I am using Angular for server-side rendering.

Comment: There is not really anything you can do about that except for inlining your critical CSS rules. This is, as disinfor already said, just how the browser behaves and not an Angular specific issue.

Comment: Of course it breaks your layout briefly. When you hard refresh your browser, you are telling it to retrieve all new assets - that means getting your CSS file as if it were new to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

I'll put this as an answer rather than another comment saying almost the same thing but not explaining anything...

- `F5` is a basic refresh; please reload/re-render the page.
- `CTRL+F5` is a hard refresh; clear currently cached files and get fresh from the server - like you're visiting the page for the first time.

With this distinction, it's clear why a `CTRL+F5` would cause the file to be re-downloaded.

It's a good thing to have done, though, because now you know what it will look like to anyone visiting your site for the first time.

That said, the commenters are correct: you should in-line any critical/base styling that you want/need for the site to look [ok/as expected/good enough] until the css has finished downloading.

Note: IIRC Mac users can hit `CMD+Shift+R` as their version of `CTRL+F5` for a hard refresh.